# How to group(merge) several plot parts?

Tags: plotting

```
parta = ContourPlot[
y == (Sqrt[Abs[x]] + Sqrt[1 - x^2]), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1];
partb = ContourPlot[
y == (Sqrt[Abs[x]] - Sqrt[1 - x^2]), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1];
heart = JoinedCurve[parta, partb];
Show[heart, PlotRange -> All]
```

I want to join(merge) `parta` and `partb` to `heart`,then I can rotate or move only one object `heart`.But `JoinedCurve` doesn't join `parta` and `partb`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to take the `==` out of `Piecewise`.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig,thanks for your reply!I updated the question,revised the codes,please check it.

Comment: You don't need `JoinedCurve`. Just evaluate `Show[parta, partb]`

Comment: If I use `Show[parta, partb]`,I need to rotate or move 2 parts.If I can `merge parta and partb to heart`,there's only one object I need to care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ContourPlot[
    Piecewise[{
        {2*x^2 - 2*x*y + y^2, x > 0},
        {2*x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2, x <= 0}
    }] == 1, 
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1.5}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, 
    MaxRecursion -> 1
]
```

### Addednum (on your revised question)

If you must use `JoinedCurve`, then you have to apply `JoinedCurve` to the graphics primitives, i.e. `Line` objects. This can be done as follows.

Evaluate the code in your question to define `parta` and `partb`.
Note that `ContourPlot` returns a `Graphics` with a `GraphicsComplex` inside:

```
parta // InputForm // Shallow
(* Graphics[GraphicsComplex[<<2>>], {<<11>>}] *)
```

Then extract the graphics primitives and the coordinates from the `GraphicsComplex` and combine them:

```
With[{
    (* find the line object in the first figure *)
    aLine = FirstCase[parta, Line[___], Null, Infinity],
    (* extract the coordinates of the points of that line *)
    aCoords = FirstCase[parta, GraphicsComplex[coords_, ___] :> coords, Null, Infinity],
    (* find the line object in the second figure *)
    bLine = FirstCase[partb, Line[___], Null, Infinity],
    (* extract the coordinates of the points of that line *)
    bCoords = FirstCase[partb, GraphicsComplex[coords_, ___] :> coords, Null, Infinity]
  },
  Graphics[
    GraphicsComplex[
      Join[aCoords, bCoords],
      JoinedCurve[{
          {aLine},
          (* we have to shift the integers that represent the points,
            because the coordinates of the second line begin after the
            coordinates of the first line *)
          {bLine /. n_Integer :> n + Length[aCoords]}
        }, CurveClosed -> False
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Of course, if you really just want to create the figure and are not interested in the graphics primitive of the curve, then your code almost works - just replace `JoinedCurve` by `{}`:

```
parta = ContourPlot[
  y == (Sqrt[Abs[x]] + Sqrt[1 - x^2]), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1];
partb = ContourPlot[
  y == (Sqrt[Abs[x]] - Sqrt[1 - x^2]), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1];

Show[{parta, partb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Your answer works well.I am curious why mathematica has no function to do it.

Comment: @kittygirl: Normally you don't need the graphics primitive, but just the graphics itself. In that case you can use `Show` without `JoinedCurve`, as m_goldberg has suggested.